# Displaying XML file in DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I created xml file which have many tags inside  tag. I defined many clients. I tried to load xml file to DataSet and display it in DataGrid but debuger inform me that datagrid cannot find table.

```
DataSet xmlData = new DataSet();
xmlData.ReadXml("Filename", XmlReadMode.Auto);
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemSource=xmlData.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

My xml file content:

```
<Table> 
   <client> 
      <borrow_id></borrow_id> 
      <client_id></client_id> 
      <client_name></client_name> 
      <client_surname></client_surname> 
      <book_id></book_id> 
      <book_author></book_author> 
      <book_name></book_name> 
      <book_year></book_year> 
      <book_publishing></book_publishing> 
      <book_ISBN></book_ISBN> 
      <borrow_start_data></borrow_start_data> 
      <borrow_end_data></borrow_end_data> 
   </client> 
</Table>

<DataGrid Visibility="Hidden" Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
```

Please help me :)

Comment: `DataSet` has well-defined serialization format. Does your XML file fits it?

Comment: Open [ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135420(v=vs.110).aspx) documentationa and look at the fileName parameter description especially to the part between bracets.

Comment: Can you show your xaml ?

Comment: Next time please edit your question and add question related things to it not in comment.

Comment: I will remember. Any one? Some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have visible `DataGrid` with `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `True` :

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" .... />
```

Then your existing code should work fine. Just don't create new `DataGrid` instance there. Simply populate the one created in XAML above :

```
DataSet xmlData = new DataSet();
xmlData.ReadXml("Filename", XmlReadMode.Auto);
//DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();  <- don't create new one!!
dataGrid.ItemSource =                     //<- reference datagrid from your XAML
            xmlData.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```